# Using asp.net scaffolding to modify existing method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms scaffolding which is available [here](https://github.com/Superexpert/WebFormsScaffolding).
I know how to scaffold custom class in my project or adding method to existing class.

I wonder is it possible to modify existing method (e.g. add lines at the end of it).